# Missing File Exceptions.h

Tags: arm, atmel

I have just recently started using Atmel Studio 6 to program an SAM3S4A that I recently bought. When compiling, it states from inside the file "pio_handler.c" that the file "exceptions.h" is missing. There seem to be many copies of this same file lying around in various locations within the Atmel program files folder. Where can I find the correct copy of this file to include so that I may finally use this chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an Atmel board new project based on SAM3S4A. Once you have done it, go to:

> src/asf/sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/source into the Solution Explorer window.

Now make a copy of this directory structure in your won project.

Finally add each file.

Now do right click on you project name into Solution Explorer and select properties.

Select Toolchain from left side options. Now choose ARM/GNU C Compiler…Directories. Now add a new path pointing to:

> ../src/asf/sam/utils/cmsis/sam3s/source/templates

Build again